# Pandas Groupby cumulative amount

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying resample/groupby from a tick list to OHLC non-time series (range bars, volume bars etc).

## First Challenge (group by cumulative volume):

Original data DF :

```
   symbol         utime                time   price  vol   cc   cv ttype  \
id                                                                          
1   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0    5  120  120     R   
2   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0   10  735  120     R   
3   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0   20  735  120     R   
4   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0   30  735    3     R   
5   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0    5  735  147     R
```

I need "groupby" the rows until a sum of vol column <= [constant] for example 500, when achieve 500, starts to sum again...

PSEUDO:

```
vol_amount = 500

adict      = {'open': 'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close' : 'last' }

ohlc_vol   = data.groupby(df['vol'].cumsum() <= vol_amount)['price'].agg(adict)

ohlc['ticks_count'] = data.groupby(df['vol'].cumsum() <= vol_amount)['vol'].count()
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Consider splitting the cumulative sum of *volume* by multiples of *vol_amount* using the integer division operator of the double forward slash, `//`. Then use that grouping in *price* aggregations:

```
vol_amount = 100

data['volcum'] = data['vol'].cumsum()
data['volcumgrp'] = data['volcum'] - ((data['volcum'] // vol_amount) * vol_amount)


adict = {'open': 'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close' : 'last'}

ohlc_vol = data.groupby(['volcumgrp'])['price'].agg(adict)
ohlc_vol['ticks_count'] = data.groupby(['volcumgrp'])['vol'].count()
```

---

To demonstrate with data using repeated stacks of posted dataframe:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = '''
id  symbol         utime                time   price  vol   cc   cv ttype
1   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0    5  120  120     R   
2   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0   10  735  120     R   
3   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0   20  735  120     R   
4   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0   30  735    3     R   
5   DOLX16  1.476961e+09 2016-10-20 09:00:37  3179.0    5  735  147     R
'''

data = pd.concat([pd.read_table(StringIO(text), sep="\s+"),
                  pd.read_table(StringIO(text), sep="\s+"),
                  pd.read_table(StringIO(text), sep="\s+"),
                  pd.read_table(StringIO(text), sep="\s+"),
                  pd.read_table(StringIO(text), sep="\s+")])

# RANDOMIZE PRICE FOR DEMO
from random import randint, seed
seed(a=48)
data['price'] = [float(randint(3175,3199)) for i in range(25)]

# VOLUME CUMULATIVE GROUP
vol_amount = 100
data['volcum'] = data['vol'].cumsum()
data['volcumgrp'] = data['volcum'] - ((data['volcum'] // vol_amount) * vol_amount)
print(data)

# PRICE AGGREGATION
adict = {'open': 'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close' : 'last'}
ohlc_vol = data.groupby(['volcumgrp'])['price'].agg(adict)
ohlc_vol['ticks_count'] = data.groupby(['volcumgrp'])['vol'].count()
print(ohlc_vol)
```

**Output**

***data df*** (in every 100 groupings)

```
       id        symbol       utime      time   price  vol   cc   cv ttype  volcum  volcumgrp
1  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3192.0    5  120  120     R       5          5
2  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3185.0   10  735  120     R      15         15
3  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3179.0   20  735  120     R      35         35
4  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3192.0   30  735    3     R      65         65
5  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3197.0    5  735  147     R      70         70
1  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3192.0    5  120  120     R      75         75
2  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3184.0   10  735  120     R      85         85
3  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3191.0   20  735  120     R     105          5
4  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3181.0   30  735    3     R     135         35
5  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3197.0    5  735  147     R     140         40
1  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3199.0    5  120  120     R     145         45
2  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3188.0   10  735  120     R     155         55
3  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3180.0   20  735  120     R     175         75
4  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3179.0   30  735    3     R     205          5
5  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3196.0    5  735  147     R     210         10
1  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3178.0    5  120  120     R     215         15
2  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3190.0   10  735  120     R     225         25
3  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3195.0   20  735  120     R     245         45
4  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3182.0   30  735    3     R     275         75
5  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3181.0    5  735  147     R     280         80
1  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3199.0    5  120  120     R     285         85
2  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3191.0   10  735  120     R     295         95
3  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3192.0   20  735  120     R     315         15
4  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3191.0   30  735    3     R     345         45
5  DOLX16  1.476961e+09  2016-10-20  09:00:37  3179.0    5  735  147     R     350         50
```

***ohlc_vol df***

```
             open     low    high   close  ticks_count
volcumgrp                                             
5          3192.0  3179.0  3192.0  3179.0            3
10         3196.0  3196.0  3196.0  3196.0            1
15         3185.0  3178.0  3192.0  3192.0            3
25         3190.0  3190.0  3190.0  3190.0            1
35         3179.0  3179.0  3181.0  3181.0            2
40         3197.0  3197.0  3197.0  3197.0            1
45         3199.0  3191.0  3199.0  3191.0            3
50         3179.0  3179.0  3179.0  3179.0            1
55         3188.0  3188.0  3188.0  3188.0            1
65         3192.0  3192.0  3192.0  3192.0            1
70         3197.0  3197.0  3197.0  3197.0            1
75         3192.0  3180.0  3192.0  3182.0            3
80         3181.0  3181.0  3181.0  3181.0            1
85         3184.0  3184.0  3199.0  3199.0            2
95         3191.0  3191.0  3191.0  3191.0            1
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants @Parfait

Comment: Hopefully, OP and future readers are not confused with data demo where 100 is used instead of 500 and repeat data from OP's post is used to have enough data. Both *vol_amount* and actual *data* can easily be changed out.

Answer (score 0):

How about the ol' "cumsum" trick:

```
import pandas as pd
def grouper(df, threshold=500):
    df['new_bin'] = 0
    cum_vol = 0
    for i in df.index:
        if cum_vol >= threshold:
            df.loc[i, 'new_bin'] = 1
            cum_vol = 0
        cum_vol += df.loc[i, "vol"]
    df['group'] = df['new_bin'].cumsum()
    return df.drop("new_bin", axis=1)


df = pd.DataFrame({"price" : [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6],
                  "vol": [100, 300, 101, 100, 402, 103, 300, 100, 30]})

df = grouper(df)
print df

   price  vol  group
0      1  100      0
1      2  300      0
2      3  101      0
3      2  100      1
4      4  402      1
5      5  103      2
6      6  300      2
7      7  100      2
8      6   30      3


adict  = {'open': 'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close' : 'last' }
print df.groupby("group")['price'].agg(adict)

       high  close  open  low
group                        
0         3      3     1    1
1         4      4     2    2
2         7      7     5    5
3         6      6     6    6

print df.groupby("group")['vol'].sum()

group
0    501
1    502
2    503
3     30
```